# insert a record in sqliteDB using ionic framework

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework

i tried inserting an record in Sqllite Db and trying to view that in

> DB Browser for SQLlite. 
>   Error : DB opened: soora.db
>           no such table UserSignIn

I created an DB and a table named 'UserSignIn' and dropped that file into www folder. Iam running this in android platform.

js file:

```
   .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaSQLite) {
     $scope.insert = function(username,password,email,mobile) {
            var db =  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "soora.db",createFromLocation: 0});
            db.transaction(function(tx) {                                                                                                                                              
            var query = "INSERT INTO UserSignIn(username, password,email,mobile) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
                  tx.executeSql(query, [],function(tx,res) {
                    console.log("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
                    $scope.statusMessage = "Data saved successful, cheers!";
                },
                function (err) {
                    $scope.statusMessage = "Error on saving: " + error.message;
                    console.error(err);
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying this in a device or emulator?

Comment: Yes iam using emulator (Geny Motion).

Comment: Then you need to use $cordovaSQLite, I put this on answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do transaction like this:

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();    
 $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [])
     .then(function (res) {
          deferred.resolve(res);
      }, function (error) {
           deferred.reject(error);
 });
 return deferred.promise;
```

Also, when device, open the database like:

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("TrivialLite.db");
```